# Can all my classes be singletons?

Tags: singleton, selenium-webdriver, gui-testing, pageobjects

I'm implementing a project where I'm testing my UI. So, each part of my UI is a separate class(Seleniums page object pattern). Now, since it's just a single web page I'm testing, according to me, theres just gotta be one instance of my UI components, while they do change state, I don't see the benefits of multiple instance of these components floating around.

So, I'm tempted to make all of them singletons, is that a bad practice?

#### For example -

|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                                            |
|                                                                            |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                      |                                     |
|                                      |                                     |
|                                      |                                     |
|                                      |                                     |
|                                      |                                     |
|                                      |                                     |
|                                      |                                     |
|                                      |                                     |
|                                      |                                     |
|                                      |                                     |
|                                      |                                     |
|                                      |                                     |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|

All of these sections will stay on my page throughout the users session, but they may change state, like toggle, resize, change the data within them, etc.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ideas implemented by the page object gem (via Ruby) is to encapsulate the instantiation of your page classes using a page factory type of object. In particular, this is the 'on_page' method, the usage is like

```
on_page(MyPageClass) do |page|
  page.do_actions
end
```

Where the block provided should have a single argument to which the instance created in the factory is passed to.

Perhaps you can employ a similar idea. It's better to have instances of page classes in my opinion; my reasoning is that your page class actions should be 'memoryless'.

Comment: Thanks @JimPedid, but I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I'm using Seleniums PageFactory class to do the initializations for me. So you're right there. Could you elaborate on "Your page class actions should be 'memoryless'?

Comment: Memoryless means you shouldn't store information in page classes to be used later. Making an instance of a page class that exists in a certain scope helps ensure this idea.

One of the problems with singleton classes is that they tend to be 'global scope', and you might be tempted to store information for later use in them.